# Best strategy to try when Spring JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate() fails

Tags: spring, spring-data

The following code uses **JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate()** to insert rows into  the database;

```
Map<String,Object>[] batchValues = ...;
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, batchValues);
```

When it fails, a DataAccessException is thrown.
I don't see anyway to determine which rows (that is, entries in the map), were problematic and caused the exception. Currently, when such an exception is thrown, we simply attempt to insert each row independently. Is there a better approach?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities and decision should be made according to the requirement.

1. Rollback the transaction and try again. This depends on type of exception. If there is constraint violation exception, then only way is to correct the data and retry the operation.
   This is a good approach where all or none is followed. You exactly know whether you have done the database operation or not.
2. batchUpdate gives you update count. AFAIK, you can safely consider this as the number of rows updated in the batch list. This might be problematic when jdbc driver does not support batch updates, spring automatically falls back to single statement execution. This method is better to use when the operation is redo-able.

Comment: The problem is that as far as I can see, batchUpdate() only returns an update count for each operation in the batch when the batch actually completes - otherwise DataAccessException is thrown and there is no way to easilly identify which 'rows' were problematic. It would be great if there was some way of identifying these.

Comment: The `DataAccessException` should contain the cause, which should be a `java.sql.BatchUpdateException` from which you can also retrieve the update counts (when set by the underlying JDBC provider that is).

Answer (score 0):

You can get failed batch like below...

```java
try {
    this.jdbCtemplate.batchUpdate(QueryConstant.SAVE_USER_NOTIFICATION, batchValues.toArray(new Map[usersResponse.size()]));
} catch (DataAccessException e) {
    int[] updateCounts = ((BatchUpdateException) e.getCause()).getUpdateCounts();
    int count = 1;
    for (int i : updateCounts) {
       if (i == Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED) {
          failedBatch.add(count);
       }
       count++;
    }
    logger.info("Batch {} failed out of {} ",failedBatch, usersResponse.size());    }
```

Comment: I see that for postgreSQL running Spring 2,0 and JDBCTemplate, even if only one of my record fails, I get a EXECUTE_FAILED for all of them, is there a way around this?